# Mailchimp repeatable section name

Tags: python, python-2.7, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I created Mailchimp Template with a repeatable section like this:

```
<div class="article" mc:repeatable="article">
    <h3 mc:edit="headline">Headline</h3>
    <p mc:edit="author">Author</p>
</div>
```

When I use the Mailchimp API Playground to check the default-content (GET templates/my_template_id/default-content) for this template, the repeatable section is displayed as repeat_1.

So when I need to set a campaign content using this template, I must fill parameter with:

```
{'template': {'id': 9999, 'sections': {'repeat_1': [{'headline': 'Headline01', 'author': 'author01'}, {'headline': 'Headline02', 'authors': 'author02'}]}}}
```

It works fine on this way, but is there any way I can use a better naming? I wouldn't like to keep it as repeat_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a message from Mailchimp support.

> As for renaming the sections of the template, that flexibility is not quite there yet. For now, those names will be populated automatically.